# Yahoo Fantasy Sports API Previous Years Stats

Tags: api, statistics, yahoo

So looking at the features of Yahoo's Fantasy Sports API, it seems that most of the gathering data abilities refers to data that can be collected in a currently active league or a league that people have played in in the past.

Is there a way for the API to access hard data from the past (let's say the year 2013) such as the passing yards of all QBs or rushing yards of all running backs without having to sign into a league?

Or would we need to just scrape it ourselves off of websites?

On another note, does Yahoo release projected points?

Comment: You might be able to get it off of a public league ID if you knew the ID.  I haven't tried anything but my own leagues, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the API

> seasons   Any valid seasons   /games;seasons=2011,2012

This shows that you can filter the data to get info from specific seasons meaning that whatever information you want you can get through filters. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think this only allows me to access data if i've played in leagues during those years, which I unfortunately have not.